# how can sync clients connect to twisted server

Tags: python, twisted

I'm new to twisted. I was wondering if I can use multiple sync clients to connect to a twisted server? Or I have to make the client twisted as well?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try it and let us know how it goes!

Comment: @benten  actually I haven't tried it yet. but do believe it. Otherwise, twisted is a bad design because a server should never ever care what the client's inner design is, nor it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients do not have to be written w/ twisted (they don't even have to be written in Python); they just have to use a protocol that your server supports.